# Restrict find/replace region

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I have a macro to clean up raw input phone numbers, and it generally works great, **except** after the rare occasions when I've done a global (workbook) find or replace.  If I have a brain fart & forget to change from "workbook" back to "sheet" mode it will run rampant, higgledy-piggledy extracting '-' & '.' out of data & formulae alike on **all** sheets in the workbook, irrespective of the constraints that I *thought* I'd applied to it.

How do I constrain it properly, so I don't have to spend a couple hours several times a year restoring?

What I have now:

```
Sheets("Data").Select  
Range("DataTbl[[Phone]:[Phone2]]").Select  ' DataTbl is 15 col x >800 row
Selection.Replace What:="  ", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
Selection.Replace What:=" ", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
Selection.Replace What:=")", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
Selection.Replace What:="-", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
Selection.Replace What:="(", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
Selection.Replace What:=".", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stop relying on `.Select` and `Selection` to define your area of concern. It may work some or even most of the time but can only lead to eventual errors due to the inherent ambiguous nature.

```
Dim r As Range
On Error Resume Next
Set r = Cells.Find(What:=vbNullString, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                 SearchOrder:=xlRows, LookAt:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False)
On Error GoTo 0
With Sheets("Data").Range("DataTbl[[Phone]:[Phone2]]")  ' DataTbl is 15 col x >800 row
    .Replace What:="  ", Replacement:=vbNullString, LookAt:=xlPart
    .Replace What:=" ", Replacement:=vbNullString, LookAt:=xlPart
    .Replace What:=")", Replacement:=vbNullString, LookAt:=xlPart
    .Replace What:="-", Replacement:=vbNullString, LookAt:=xlPart
    .Replace What:="(", Replacement:=vbNullString, LookAt:=xlPart
    .Replace What:=".", Replacement:=vbNullString, LookAt:=xlPart
End With
```

See [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA macros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros) for various methods to get away from `.Select`.

**EDIT:** Added four lines of code at the beginning to reset the 'remembered' `.Find` parameters to defaults (e.g. *Within: Sheet*, not *Within: Workbook*).

Comment: Unfortunately that behaved the same way.  Worked fine when Find/Replace was in Sheet mode, but not in Workbook.  :(

Comment: @DeinaUnderhill - I've added the minimal amount of code necessary to reset the 'remembered' `.Find/.Replace` options to defaults.